# Set an Icon in QMenu with Stylesheet?

Tags: qt, icons, qmenu, qstylesheet

how can i set an Icon for a QAction in QMenu through Stylesheet?

for example:

```
QMenu* menu = new QMenu();

QAction* action1= new QAction();
QACtion* action2= new QAction();

menu->addAction(action1);
menu->addAction(action2);
```

now i want to set different icon for action1 and action2 with QT Stylesheet.

Is it possible with Stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stylesheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) only apply to widgets.

> Qt Style Sheets are a powerful mechanism that allows you to customize
>   the appearance of **widgets**, in addition to what is already possible by
>   subclassing QStyle.

`QAction` is not a widget, thus you can't add an icon to a `QAction` via the style sheets. However, you could probably have a shot with `QActionWidget` and for example a `QLabel`, even if it can be tricky.